# What's an effective way to earn money in Etrian Odyessy 3?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-3

I've played Etrian Odyssey games before, but I never recall having quite as much trouble with money as I am in Etrian Odyssey 3. I find myself constantly broke, and sometimes not even able to afford resting at an INN. There are a couple methods I can think of, like fishing, but considering since there's a cost associated with going out in the ship it doesn't seem like it would provide much profit. I'm still only in the first stratum, so it's possible this will cease being a problem later on, but for now I find myself in a really difficulty situation.

What's an effective way to to earn money in Etrian Odyssey 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the time to level up a farmer, and I've discovered that Harvesting is an excellent source of revenue, since items from harvesting nodes sell for a lot more than items dropped by monsters. For harvesting to be profitable you real need to level up your farmer so you can max out **Harvestry**. Leveling up **Double Crop** is is also really effective for increasing your profits, provided you don't level it to the point your farmer can no longer afford to cast it.